# Cookie not being read by html form

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, cookies

I am working on a website where people can search based on their postalcode.
When the visit the page for the first time a popup dialog opens. You have to fill in your Postalcode and a radisu of x km.

when submit the cookies are set as 'postalcode' and 'radius'.

I print out these cookies in a searchbar on the mainpage. but when I want to submit the form it is not getting the value of the cookie. it is not empty but when I retype it manually and then click submit it works. what could be the problem?

I am using Pro6pp (an online postcode database) from which i get postalcodes in a specific radius. i save those in a SESSION.

My dialog:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden" title="Welkom bij OostWestRegioBest.nl">

    <p>Zoeken in uw regio.</p>
    <p>Voer een postcode in zonder letters. Voorbeeld: 1234.</p>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="">

        <input type="text" name="postcode" size="25" placeholder="Postcode">
        <select name="radius">
            <option disabled selected>Afstand</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
        </select> 
        <br/><br/>
        <hr>
        <br/>
            <p style="float: right"><input type="submit" value="Opslaan"></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="afstand" value="true" />

</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['postcode']))
    {
        setcookie('radius', $_POST['radius'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie('postcode', $_POST['postcode'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    };
?>
```

My searchform:

```
    <form name="input" method="post" action="searchresults" class="pro6pp_range">
    <input type="search" onchange="validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="70">
          <select class="range">
          <? $radius = $this->input->cookie('radius'); ?>
          <? $sesspc = $_SESSION['searched_post_code'] = $_COOKIE['postcode']; ?>
          <? $postcode = $sesspc ?>
            <option selected="selected" value="<?= $this->input->cookie('radius'); ?>"><?= $this->input->cookie('radius');?> km</option>
            <option value="">Kies een afstand</option>
            <option value="5">5 km</option>
            <option value="10">10 km</option>
            <option value="15">15 km</option>
            <option value="20">20 km</option>
            <option value="25">25 km</option>
            <option value="50">50 km</option>
          </select>
        <input type="search" required="required" name="searchpc" class="postcode" value="<?= $postcode ?>" placeholder="Postcode (1234)" maxlength="4">

        <input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
        <br/>
        <span class="message"></span>
        <br/>
    </form>

<?php

$searchpc = $this->input->post('searchpc');

if(empty($searchpc)){
        unset($_SESSION['postcodes']); 
    }
?>
```

Code that interacts between the form and the pro6pp database:

```
<!--    <script>
    window.location.replace("home/searchresults");
    </script>
-->
<?php 

     session_start();

echo '<pre>';
     $new_post_code=$_GET['post_code'];
        if($new_post_code!='' && $new_post_code!=0){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['searched_post_code']) || 
        empty($_SESSION['searched_post_code'])){ 
        $_SESSION['searched_post_code']=$new_post_code; 
        $_SESSION['searched_post_code'] = $_COOKIE['postcode'];
        }elseif($_SESSION['searched_post_code']!=$new_post_code){ 

        $_SESSION['searched_post_code']=$new_post_code; 

        unset($_SESSION['postcodes']); 
        }
        }
     $string = implode($_SESSION['postcodes'], '|');
     $output=$_GET['output'];
     $_SESSION['postcodes'][]=$output;
     echo $output;
     print_r($_SESSION);
     print_r($_COOKIE);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: dont use short tag `<? ?>`

Comment: why not? what's wrong with shorttags?

Comment: because in some server short tag is disabled through php.ini

Comment: it isn't on my server. so it's no problem for me.

Comment: keep it in mind in case you need in future

Comment: i know. i use normal tags on my own page. but here i have shorttags.

Comment: where you want to post the searchform?

Answer (score 1):

**setcookie()** functions accepts few params one of them is **PATH** I've noticed you didn't set it. Setting **path** to '/' will make it avaiable within the entire domain. And it solves your problem.

example

```
 setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, '/');
```

TestCookie will have $value which expires after 1h and it will be available for entire domain.

from manual

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

You need to set proper path for your cookie in setcookie() and it will work.

More in manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Moreover:

1. Edit change keys of $_SESSION and $_COOKIE you set different keys than you checked.
2. If you remove $_SESSION variable firstly check if this variable exists with isset()
3. Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.
4. It doesn't affects question but change `onchange="validate()"` to this `onchange="return validate()"`

Code you should change

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['postcode']))
{
    setcookie('radius', $_POST['radius'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
    setcookie('postcode', $_POST['postcode'], time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
    header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
};
```

?>

---

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="searchresults" class="pro6pp_range">
<input type="search" onchange="return validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="70">
      <select class="range">
      <? $radius = isset($_COOKIE['radius']) ? $_COOKIE['radius'] : -1; ?>
      <? if(isset($_COOKIE['postcode'])) {$sesspc = $_COOKIE['postcode']; $_SESSION['postcode']= $_COOKIE['postcode'];} ?>
      <? $postcode = $sesspc ?>
      <? if(isset($_COOKIE['radius'])
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$_COOKIE['radius'].'">'.$_COOKIE['radius'].' km</option>';
      ?>
        <option value="">Kies een afstand</option>
        <option value="5">5 km</option>
        <option value="10">10 km</option>
        <option value="15">15 km</option>
        <option value="20">20 km</option>
        <option value="25">25 km</option>
        <option value="50">50 km</option>
      </select>
    <input type="search" required="required" name="searchpc" class="postcode" value="<?= $postcode ?>" placeholder="Postcode (1234)" maxlength="4">

    <input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
    <br/>
    <span class="message"></span>
    <br/>
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['searchpc']) && isset($_SESSION['postcode']))
    {
       if(empty($_POST['searchpc']) ) unset($_SESSION['postcode']); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you have these cookies in one domain?

Comment: +1 for this... i also got the same problem in past and i solved it with using path as`'/'` but i didnt know what it affects. but now i came to know from your answer thanks

Comment: you can try it yourself too. http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/ just fill in a postcode like '9132' and a radius of 10. then click search on the mainpage. it will give you an error.

Comment: i have them in 1 domain yes.

Comment: When i type the same postalcode in the input it sets a new cookie and that works. so what could be the problem.

Comment: exactly, for me it works too. Maybe you have turned your cookies off in browser?

Comment: this error affects session? If so have you start session with session_start() on every site where you use it?

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. when i type in a postalcode in the dialog it does not work. but when i do in the searchbox on the mainpage it works.

Comment: it looks like the cookie is not read well when set in the dialog. it is when set in the searchbox itself.

Comment: From manual `Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.` maybe it is your problem. What does `print_r($_COOKIE);` shows?

Comment: they are visible because i reload the page on closing the dialog. so that's not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that is result of this function? If so then $_COOKIE['postcode'] has defined index and value. So there should not be any error. Does it work now?

Comment: that's the strange thing. i use the session 'searched_post_code' to search postcodes but i specified it as $_SESSION['searched_post_code'] = $_COOKIE['postcode']; is that the right way? maybe that's the problem.

Comment: if you want to store cookie postcode variable in session searched_post_code variable then it is correct. Make sure your session is started. After you changed it are there any errors? Assigment to $_SESSION should not cause this error, rather getting the value of $_SESSION['searched_post_code'] maybe you get value of it before assigment

Comment: my session is started. but in someway the database for postcodes from pro6pp is not reading the searched_post_code in the right way.

Comment: `if(empty($searchpc)){
        if(isset($_SESSION['postcode'])) unset($_SESSION['postcode']); 
    }` try this and watch out for proper keys for $_SESSION check if $_SESSION exits before you unset it

Comment: where do I need to add that?

Comment: In your search form and whereever you want to read variable content. Also to make such notices not to be shown use this `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

Comment: you can do it with error_reporting() function or you can use  `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ` Remember to include this part of code to every site and the best place is top of a page. And please don't write that after doing it you still have errors cause it is impossible

Comment: Also do it in $this->input->cookie() function and every input function because if it tries to get unassigned variable php will throw NOTICE.

Comment: after I've added your code. the undefined variable postcodes is gone but the error undefined variable searched_post_code appears. I can't get the line $_SESSION['searched_post_code'] = $_COOKIE['postcode']; to work now.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into the question. If you have an answer, post it as an answer.  The comments will be purged -- if you want to keep something, put it somewhere else.

Comment: The question was about cookies and problem was solved as George suggested post another question and put the code that fails with error message. It's really hard to follow all of your code modifications when we don't have access to whole code to debug it.